# How To Get An Array From Splitted String That Has Negative Value

Tags: javascript, arrays, arraylist, negative-number, columnsorting

I don't know what is the right question for this.

I want to make this number -800 become [-8,0,0] is anyone can build it

The first thing that I do, is to make the number become a string and using the map function I iterate it becomes an array like this

```js
const number = -800;
const numberString = number.toString();
const arrayString = numberString.split``.map((x) => +x);

console.log(arrayString)
```

But the result is `[ NaN, 8, 0, 0 ]`

How to change the `NaN` and first index `8` become `-8` without disturbing the other index. So it becomes `[-8, 0, 0]`

Is anybody can help me?

Thanks.

Comment: I recommend accepting Hao Wu's answer, it'll be more performant than mine I believe

Comment: Thanks Nick, i think you both give the great answer. But yesterday you commenting first, so i use your answer. Well, i will change it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `numberString.match(/-?\d/g)` instead of `split`

```js
const number = -800;
const numberString = number.toString();
const arrayString = numberString.match(/-?\d/g).map(x => +x);

console.log(arrayString)
```

Comment: Oh, this is better than mine

Comment: @Nick They are about equal when it comes to the performance:  
https://jsfiddle.net/9evxz6rj/1/  vs  
https://jsfiddle.net/9evxz6rj/0/

Answer (score 3):

One possible solution is to just do this operation on the absolute value and, during the `map`, check if the number was negative (only for the first index).

```js
const number = -800;
const numberString = Math.abs(number).toString();
const arrayString = numberString.split``.map((x, i) => i == 0 && number < 0 ? -x : +x);

console.log(arrayString)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're not clear about `Regex`, you can use `Array.from` to convert a string to an array number. Then handle the first number based on the sign of original number.

```js
console.log(convertNumberToArray(800));
console.log(convertNumberToArray(-800));

function convertNumberToArray(number){
  var result = Array.from(Math.abs(number).toString(), Number);
  result[0] *= number <= 0 ? -1 : 1;
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use String#match with regex which matches optional - with the dig it.

```js
var number = -800;
var numberString = number.toString().match(/-?\d/g);
var numberInt = [];

for (var i = 0; i < numberString.length; i++) {
    numberInt.push(parseInt(numberString[i]));
}
console.log(numberInt);
```